# Looking for a solution to API Identity and Authorization Management

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, authorization, keycloak

I've become very frustrated with the landscape of API creation and authentication/authorization. I would like to find a solution that doesn't require lots of additional complexity (creating new services myself, standing up and maintaining an instance of Keycloak, and so forth) – ideally a managed service (like Auth0 ... but Auth0 doesn't meet my requirements) – that centralizes the management of users and permissions, and allows me to add attributes to users.

Some context:

Suppose you have an API that has a variety of routes:

```
GET               /customers
GET/POST/DELETE   /customers/{id}
GET               /customers/{id}/orders
GET/POST/DELETE   /customers/{id}/orders
```

You can imagine that you have a case where you have users that have read-only access, and others that can read, create and delete customers and orders. You can also imagine that you may have the need to programmatically access the API, via a service account or access token (such as with Github PATs).

This could be set up with FastAPI or some other framework, such that when a route is accessed it checks that the user, or the access token – or in essence the credentials being used to access the API – has the necessary permissions.

What would be ideal, then, is to have a system that allows me to create users, and from that system the users can – provided they have the permissions in the identity management system to do so – create machine credentials (again, like with Github PATs, but perhaps something that can generate a JWT for consistency of credentials). Users can be added to groups that provide them with roles, and therefore permissions, or they can be assigned roles directly. Ultimately, it's a system that:

1. Allows user creation and management
2. Allows users to be grouped, groups can have roles that cascade to users
3. Allows users to be assigned to roles directly
4. Allow users to create credentials for programmatic access
5. Does not make management of users, roles, and so forth, onerous
6. Allows services (such as a REST API) using these identities for authentication to get the permissions and other information associated with credentials. In the case of other information, this could be included as claims in a JWT – this would require a system that allows claims to be added programmatically to the ID token/JWT.

In my experience, the closest thing to this is Keycloak. Unfortunately, it is a decent amount of work to maintain a Keycloak instance. Still, Keycloak does not provide number 4 in the list above. Does anyone else have experience addressing this issue? I would like to avoid have to manage users and permissions myself, because I have limited resources and that isn't my area of expertise.

Similar solutions:

Keycloak – hits most of the points, except for allowing users to create machine credentials. I'd like to avoid having to set up and maintain a Keycloak instance. Not sure if I can add attributes (claims or something else) to a machine/service account JWT.
Auth0 – Hits some of these, but doesn't allow me to add attributes to machine/service account JWTs, although it will add permissions to them (but that isn't enough).